# Python: Unable to remove newline from str

Tags: python, shell

This is kind of weird but here it goes.

Below is some code that opens a file as a log, and pipes some console output into it. Later on I open that file and would like to copy the contents of the file (each line is a directory path of a file) into my current directory, however my shell returns an error saying it can't find the file because it has a newline attached to it. When I print the line within the script it doesn't have a newline, but when I try to copy it within the script it does, what gives?

```
with open("log.txt", 'a+') as log:
    for something in something_else:
        p1 = subprocess.Popen(["script.py", "-x", "-options"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
        p2 = subprocess.Popen(["egrep", 'abc|xyz'], stdin=p1.stdout, stdout=log, universal_newlines=True)
        p1.stdout.close()
        output = p2.communicate()[0] #Debug purposes
```

Later on...

```
with open("log.txt") as log2:
    for line in log2:
        line = re.sub(".pattern", "pattern", line)
        line.rstrip() #doesn't work
        call(['cp', line, '.'])
```

My shell returns: cp cannot stat `path/to/dir**\n**' no such file or directory

Comment: can you try call(['cp', line[:-x], '.']). Try to set x to 1 first and see if the newlines is gone?

Comment: `universal_newlines=True` has no effect here. The redirection occurs at the file descriptor level (`p1.stdout.fileno()`, `log.fileno()`). `output` is `None` here.

Comment: you could use `shutil.copy(line, '.')` instead of `call(['cp', line, '.'])`.

Comment: you could use `if re.search('abc|xyz', line): log.write(line)` instead of `egrep` process. You could put code into a function and use `import script; result = script.do_something(*args)` instead of `script.py` process.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Strings are immutable in Python, use `line = line.rstrip()` instead.

Comment: This worked.. yikes, showing my python novice level here. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 3):

It is because `line.rstrip()` returns a copy of the original string (see [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html)).

So something like `line = line.rstrip()` should do the job.

Comment: @liquid no worries, that one has tripped me once as well :)